# Телеграмм бот не видит администрацию сообщества

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Я использую следующую функцию для проверки, подписан ли человек на мой канал перед использованием бота. (pytelegrambotapi)

```
def check_subscription(chat_id, user_id):
    chat_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
    return chat_member.status == 'member'
```

Эта функция отлично работает для обычных юзеров, однако не видит администрацию и всех у кого есть роли, подскажите, как можно ее преобразовать

Comment: Попробуйте использовать метод get_chat_administrators(chat_id) -> https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/507d524215433b72f34271ad00acb2a530791f05/telebot/apihelper.py#L266

Comment: Так же стоит участь, что помимо статуса 'member', существуют статусы 'creator', 'administrator', 'restricted', 'left', 'kicked'. Но не факт что это get_chat_member возвращает пользователей с данными статусами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вариант решения этой задачи, он заключается в проверке статусов помимо `'member'`:

```
def check_subscription(chat_id, user_id):
    chat_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
    return chat_member.status in ['administrator', 'member']
```

Можно так же использовать [`get_chat_administrators`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/507d524215433b72f34271ad00acb2a530791f05/telebot/apihelper.py#L266) для получения списка администраторов:

```
def check_subscription(chat_id, user_id):
    # проверяем является ли member
    chat_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
    is_member = chat_member.status == 'member'
    # если нет, то проверим по списку админов
    if not is_member:
        chat_admins = bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id)
        for admin in chat_admins:
            if admin.user.id == user_id:
                is_member = True
                break
    return is_member
```

Таким образом, если пользователь является участником чата или администратором, функция вернет `True`, в противном случае - `False`.

P.S. Существует так же статус в `get_chat_member`, называемый как 'creator' - это статус относится к создателю чата. Функция `get_chat_administrators` в свою очередь не возвращает создателя чата. Стоит учитывать данное при проверке пользователей из чата в телеграмм.